# Using RSpec how can I test the results of a rescue exception block

Tags: ruby, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have a method that has a begin / rescue block in it.  How do I test the rescue block using RSpec2?

```
class Capturer

  def capture
    begin
      status = ExternalService.call
      return true if status == "200"
      return false
    rescue Exception => e
      Logger.log_exception(e)
      return false
    end
  end

end

describe "#capture" do
  context "an exception is thrown" do
    it "should log the exception and return false" do
      c = Capturer.new
      success = c.capture
      ## Assert that Logger receives log_exception
      ## Assert that success == false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: FYI see [Why is it bad style to `rescue Exception => e` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048173/211563).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`should_receive`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-8/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message) and [`should be_false`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-8/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers):

```
context "an exception is thrown" do
  before do
    ExternalService.stub(:call) { raise Exception }
  end

  it "should log the exception and return false" do
    c = Capturer.new
    Logger.should_receive(:log_exception)
    c.capture.should be_false
  end
end
```

Also note that you should **not** be rescuing from `Exception`, but something more specific. `Exception` covers *everything*, which is almost definitely not what you want. At the most you should be rescuing from `StandardError`, which is the default.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't raise the exception.

Comment: Your question doesn't really ask for that part, but I've updated my question with it anyway, as well as an additional note.

Comment: It specifically asks **How do I test the rescue block using RSpec2?**

Comment: And your title specifically says "the results of the rescue block". It doesn't matter, does my updated answer help?

Comment: It works, however the c.capture call needs to be wrapped in a lambda block.  Thanks!